# Clear user session on profile change

Tags: restricted-profiles

My wife's company want to loan android tablets (Nexus 7's with 5.0 in the pilot) to clients for the duration of a consultation.  Restricted profiles in lollypop make this more achievable.  Question : is there a way when the client has finished to wipe his/her data automatically?  Obviously an app would be ideal but writing something might work.  The use cases are basically privacy (obviously) but also ensuring that users don't leave anything inappropriate for the next user.

I currently write java apps on unix but am a novice with android.  Is it possible for instance to write something that listens for a profile change event?  A restricted user "template" with allowed apps prepopulated so the user profile could be quickly deleted and recreated?

Comment: Well, I don't think for doing the same if an app is available or not but the idea of creating an app that does the same thing is something in which I would say a big yes ! Like you sad that you  have the knowledge of Java means you can start using the Eclipse to get your own application developed! Writing a code over the Android environment is super easy and if you have working knowledge with java then I would say there's nothing much to worry about I am sure you can take care of most of the things give it a try and if you still ran onto trouble then you always have the option to developed...

Answer (score 0):

I think Guest Mode is made exactly for this purpose:
http://www.androidbeat.com/2015/01/activate-guest-mode-android-5-lollipop/

As far as I can tell, when you exit guest mode, it deletes any data/settings they have entered.  The only downside is that you would need to reinstall any special apps you want clients to be able to use.